# Is there a simple way to play a sound in a background thread using SFML

Tags: c++, multithreading, sfml

I am trying to play a song in a background thread of my GUI application so that the song doesn't block the GUI thread. Is there a simple way to do this with either std::thread or SFML Threads?

I have tried using std::thread for this, but it still blocks the GUI thread when I call `my_thread.join()`.

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
#include <thread>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

void func() {
    sf::Music music;
    music.openFromFile("mysong.wav");
    music.play();
    // if I don't have usleep here the function exits immediately
    // why is that exactly???
    usleep(100000000);
}


int main() {

    std::thread my_thread(func);
    my_thread.join();

    // this is where I would process events/build windows in GUI
    while(1)
        std::cout << "here"; // <--- Want this to run while song plays

}
```

Comment: You don't have to use threads, you just call sf::Sound::play() for an sf::Sound instance

Comment: Your best bet based off of what you written here would be to store sf::Music somewhere(Usually a class or an audio manager of sorts) and have it play the music so it doesn't stop the second the second your function ends.

Comment: You may enjoy my Jukebox class : https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Source%3A-Jukebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in SFML you need to have a valid sf::Sound or sf::Music for music to play, when that variable gets destroyed you will no longer have a valid reference to that object a possible solution for the code you posted would be something like this:

```
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

class CAudio
{
    sf::Music music;
public:
    void func()
    {
        music.openFromFile("mysong.wav");
        music.play();
    }

    sf::Status getStatus() 
    {
        return music.getStatus();
    }
}    

int main() {

    CAudio my_music;
    my_music.func();

    // http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/SoundSource_8hpp_source.php
    while(my_music.getStatus() == sf::Status::Playing) 
    {
        std::cout << "here"; // <--- Want this to run while song plays
    }

}
```

Also, always use brackets, regardless if its a 1 line statement always use brackets, I know its allowed but it will make your life easier when you troubleshoot later on.